# Вызов метода из одного RecyclerView.Adapter в другом RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть два RecyclerView. В первом (CategoriesRV) отображаются категории, а в другом (ElementsRV) элементы этих категорий. При добавлении элементов в ElementsRV сразу задаются категории из CategoriesRV.

Допустим, в CategoriesRV добавлено 3 категории, а в ElementsRV десяток элементов, каждый из которых привязан к той или иной категории. В CategoriesRV реализовано удаление категорий. Я удаляю одну из них, но в ElementsRV продолжает отображаться эта удалённая категория. В момент удаления из CategoriesRV необходимо "дёргать" метод из ElementsRV для очистки упоминаний об удалённой категории.

Пока додумался только до такой реализации:

Метод из адаптера CategoriesRV

```
private void deleteCategory() {
            CategoryModel currentCategory = categoryModels.get(getAdapterPosition());
            SharedPreferences spCategories = context.getSharedPreferences("spCategories",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            spCategories.edit().remove(currentCategory.getCategoryId()).apply();
            categoryModels.remove(currentCategory);
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.preset_deleted,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            ElementsRV.deleteItem(context);
        }
```

ElementsRV.deleteItem(context) - метод из адаптера ElementsRV:

```
public static void deleteItem(Context context){
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("spCategories", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (int i = 0; i < recipesModelList.size(); i++){
            if (!sp.contains(recipesModelList.get(i).getCategoryName())){
                recipesModelList.get(i).setCategoryName("");
                recipesModelList.get(i).setCategoryBtnColor(0);
                recipesModelList.get(i).setCategoryTextColor(0);
                notifyItemChanged(i); // Non-static method 'notifyItemChanged(int)' cannot be referenced from a static context
            }
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что notifyItemChanged() не может вызываться из статичного метода. Как быть в этой ситуации?

**UPD**: Проблема с доступом решена. Теперь появился другой вопрос. Во вьюшке элемента из ElementsRV есть пометка о привязанной категории. Методы, написанные ниже, её убирают только из файла SharedPrefences, а на самой вьюхе после удаления остаётся. Пропадает только при повтороном входе в это активити. Пробовал и notifyDataSetChanged(), и notifyItemChanged().

CategoriesRV

```
private void deleteCategory() {
            CategoryModel currentCategory = categoryModels.get(getAdapterPosition());
            SharedPreferences spCategories = context.getSharedPreferences("spCategories",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            spCategories.edit().remove(currentCategory.getCategoryId()).apply();
            categoryModels.remove(currentCategory);
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.preset_deleted,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            ElementsRV erv = new ElementsRV ();
            erv.deleteItem(context, currentCategory.getCategoryName(), recipesAdapter);
    }
```

ElementsRV

```
public  void deleteItem(Context context, String categoryName, ElementsRV erv){
        SharedPreferences.Editor spRecipes;
        for (int i = 0; i < recipesModelList.size(); i++){
            if (recipesModelList.get(i).getCategoryName().equals(categoryName)){
                spRecipes = context.getSharedPreferences(recipesModelList.get
                        (i).getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                spRecipes.putString("categoryName", "");
                spRecipes.putInt("categoryBtnColor", 0);
                spRecipes.putInt("categoryTextColor", 0);
                spRecipes.apply();
                recipesModelList.get(i).setCategoryName("");
                recipesModelList.get(i).setCategoryBtnColor(0);
                recipesModelList.get(i).setCategoryTextColor(0);
            }
        }
        erv.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: notifyItemChanged находится в ElementsRV?

Comment: @Komdosh Да, там.

Comment: а ссылка на ElementsRV есть у CategoriesRV?

Comment: а почему просто не удалить элемент из списка? recipesModelList.remove(i); Сам dataSet не поменялся, вы поменяли элемент в нём

Comment: @Komdosh дык сам элемент мне не надо удалять. Только открепить от категории.

Comment: а как у вас объявлен recipesModelList?

Comment: @Komdosh  глобально. Инициализируется в конструкторе. public ElementsRV(List<RecipeModel> recipesModelList) {
        this.recipesModelList = recipesModelList;}

Comment: а попробуйте elementsRV.invalidate(); а потом уже notifyItemChanged()

Comment: @Komdosh это же метод непосредственно самого RecyclerView. Как мне достучаться до него в адаптере?

Comment: а, да, просто вызовите invalidate перед notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @Komdosh увы, пишет, что нет такого метода.

Comment: а вы от какого класса наследуетесь?

Comment: а, ой, я путаюсь, отбой

Comment: notifyDataSetInvalidated(); Вот такой должен быть

Comment: @Komdosh и его тоже нет. public class ElementsRV extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementsRV.ElementsViewHolder>

Comment: Значит придётся всё таки изменить recipesModelList, для того чтобы адаптер всё таки увидел изменения

Comment: @Komdosh в методе deleteItem() сделал ещё один List, копию recipesModelList, и скармливаю новый лист адаптеру, но всё равно при удалении вьюшка не убирается. Только при повторном входе. Уже не знаю куда копать. Можно ли как-то запустить вручную onBindViewHolder и там уже делать проверку?

Comment: Вы можете его переписать,  `@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ... code ...
        }`

Comment: У вас проблемы с архитектурой, трудно понять что происходит. Пример работы с вложенным recycler view есть тут, возможно вам поможет это https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 1):

метод `static` принадлежит классу, он не понимает, у какого объекта надо вызвать `notifyItemChanged` поэтому нужно либо передать ссылку на объект класса ElementsRV:

```
ElementsRV.deleteItem(context, elementsRV);
```

elementsRV это экземпляр класса ElementsRV

```
public static void deleteItem(Context context, ElementsRV erv){
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("spCategories", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (int i = 0; i < recipesModelList.size(); i++){
            if (!sp.contains(recipesModelList.get(i).getCategoryName())){
                recipesModelList.get(i).setCategoryName("");
                recipesModelList.get(i).setCategoryBtnColor(0);
                recipesModelList.get(i).setCategoryTextColor(0);
                erv.notifyItemChanged(i); // Non-static method 'notifyItemChanged(int)' cannot be referenced from a static context
            }
        }
    }
```

Либо всё-таки сделать deleteItem не статическим и тогда всё будет работать правильно

```
elementsRV.deleteItem(context);
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже так сделал. Работает, но появился другой нюанс. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, в шапку. Добавил туда инфу. Может знаете в чём дело.